# Does there exist a coordinate transformation between different metrics?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have defined a distance function $d$ over a space $X$ in terms of a coordinate system. For example, the Euclidean metric in two dimensions is expressed as $d(p, q) = \sqrt{(p_x - q_x)^2 + (p_y - q_y)^2}$.

Suppose I have another distance function $d'$ over $X$, also expressed in terms of a coordinate system, for example the taxicab metric $d'(p, q) = |p_x - q_x| + |p_y - q_y|$.

Question: does there always exist for any pair of distance functions a coordinate transformation $(x, y) \to (x', y')$ such that $d(p, q) = d'(p', q')$, where $p'$ and $q'$ are $p$ and $q$ in the new coordinate system. For example, if $p = (2, 3)$ and the coordinate transformation is $(x, y) \to (x +2, y - 4)$, then $p' = (4, -1)$.

To use the taxicab metric as an example, does there exist a coordinate transformation such that for all $p, q$: $|p_{x'} - q_{x'}| + |p_{y'} - q_{y'}| = \sqrt{(p_x - q_x)^2 + (p_y - q_y)^2}$ (note: primed coordinates on the lhs, unprimed on the rhs).

I hope the question is clear! Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: The question you are asking can be stated as "does there exist an isometry between $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$", isn't it? If so, the answer is in full generality no

Comment: Hi Didier, thanks for your answer! Yes, I think that's equivalent, and of course the answer there is clear.

Comment: @Didier I don't think this is equivalent. The term "coordinate" has no meaning in a general metric space. If a point in a certain metric space is characterized for example by two (unique) real numbers (its coordinates) it means that the space is a part of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Therefore, we are not considering general metric spaces but very particular ones.

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree with you. The question being very vague and unclear, I just wanted to know if that was what the author had in mind. It seems that was the case *i.e* something like "are two metrics on an open subset of $\Bbb R^^n$ always isometric?" or something

Comment: @Didier I agree with this formulation. And the answer is "no isometry exists" : for example the "jungle river" metric is not isometric with the Euclidean metric. See [here](http://ftp.math.uni-rostock.de/pub/romako/heft67/szaz67.pdf) for example.